# Helm fails to pull chart from repo even though it exists

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, bitnami

This is my chart:

```
name: zookeeper
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  - name: bitnami/zookeeper
    version: 3.8.1
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

This is what my `helm search repo zookeeper` produces:

```
NAME                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
bitnami/zookeeper           11.1.2          3.8.1       Apache ZooKeeper provides a reliable, centraliz...
my-repo/zookeeper           11.1.2          3.8.1       Apache ZooKeeper provides a reliable, centraliz...
```

But when I try to fetch my dependencies, it says the chart doesn't exist:

```
$ helm dependency build                                                                                                                                                [11:50:45]
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "my-repo" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Error: bitnami/zookeeper chart not found in repo https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Why? It's there, so why won't it fetch it?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the name from `bitnami/zookeeper` to `zookeeper` in my chart since that's how it's defined in the [base chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/zookeeper/Chart.yaml#L20)